# The best way to implement showing "No Connection" message throughout the app

Tags: android, user-interface, popupwindow, android-snackbar

I'm developing the application-messenger and need to  show dynamically "No Connection" message in case of lack of Internet, like in popular messengers (Viber, etc).

It should look like the narrow strip below the Action Bar or below the tabs. 
What is the best way to add such view dynamically? Is it custom SnackBar or PopupWindow?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
compile 'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:1.1.1'
```

then in the code add this example:

```
TSnackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"no internet connection",TSnackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This is the library for the above, it adds snackbars under toolbars:

https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar

Comment: @H.Brooks yes it doesnt depend on the toolbar, its just a top snackbar, TSnackbar= top snackbar

Comment: I upvoted it, I think it's people that got nothing better to do.